# Mac app crashes from finder but runs inside Terminal

Tags: macos, frameworks, crash, terminal

I tried searching, but did not find a specific post that could answer my question.
For my MacOS app, I have an external framework residing in /Library/Frameworks that I am linking to.
The app runs fine from Xcode. The app runs fine by itself on my dev system. 
If I copy the app bundle over to another machine, and also copy over the external framework to /Library/Frameworks area (so it has a similar setup to my dev machine), the app crashes when it tries to perform the task that uses the external framework.

What's weird is that the app does not crash on the other machine if run from the terminal, or through gdb. It only crashes on the feature using the external framework when launched from the Finder. I made sure permissions etc are all open.
The crash is of BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) type and the feature involves using the framework to write out a file.
Any thoughts about what could be causing the crash/how to go about debugging this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely difference you're running into is working directories -- launching an application manually from the terminal will run it in whatever directory you happen to be in at the time, while launching it normally (e.g, by double-clicking it in the Finder) will start it up with a working directory of `/`. Make sure you aren't using any relative paths by mistake.

Comment: Do you mean the path of the concerning framework related to the app bundle/OS SDK? I am using an absolute path for this. Also, the app does not have issues on my dev machine when launched from the Finder. Whatever project path is relative, should have affected the way it behaved on the dev machine too..right?

Comment: Thanks for the general path hint though. Writing the file directly under / was the cause of my problem. I changed code to write it elsewhere specifically. While running from the Terminal, it appears there did not seem to be problems writing under / though.